# Solve $\cos\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)=a$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$; $y=2$ when $x=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, inverse

> $\cos\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)=a$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ ; $y=2$ when $x=0$

The general solution given in my reference as : $y=x\cos^{-1}a+C$ and the particular solution : $\cos\big(\frac{y-2}{x}\big)=a$. But, is it a complete solution ?

**Note:** It is solved in my reference by taking $\cos^{-1}\big(\cos(\frac{dy}{dx})\big)=\frac{dy}{dx}$, but is it true always ?

**My Attempt**

$$
\cos\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)=a\implies \cos\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)=\cos\big(\cos^{-1}a\big)\\
2n\pi\pm\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos^{-1}a\implies \pm{dy}=(2n\pi+\cos^{-1}a){dx}\\
\pm y=(2n\pi+\cos^{-1}a)x+C_1\\
y=\pm (2n\pi+\cos^{-1}a)x+C_2\\
\implies \color{red}{y=2n\pi x\pm x\cos^{-1}a+C_2}
$$
At $x=0$,
$$
C_2=2\\
y=2n\pi x\pm x\cos^{-1}a+2\\
\implies \cos\big(\frac{y-2}{x}\big)=\cos\big[2n\pi\pm\cos^{-1}a\big]=\cos\big[\cos^{-1}a\big]=a\\
\implies \color{red}{\cos\big(\frac{y-2}{x}\big)=a}
$$

Can I say my general solution $y=2n\pi x\pm x\cos^{-1}a+C_2$ is complete, not the one in my reference ?

Comment: What is $\mathscr{R}$ ? Did you mean $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @Rebellos yup. real number, edited OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not unique due to the periodic nature of the $\cos$ function. Suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two distinct solutions, then $\exists n$ such that

$$ \cos\left(\frac{dy_2}{dx}\right) = \cos\left(\pm\frac{dy_1}{dx}+2n\pi\right) = a $$

$$ \implies \frac{dy_2}{dx} \pm \frac{dy_1}{dx} = 2n\pi \implies y_2 \pm y_1 = 2n\pi x $$

So a more general solution would be

$$ y(x) = \left(\pm \cos^{-1}a + 2n\pi\right)x + 2 $$

It goes without saying that all of this is valid only when $a \in [-1,1]$

Comment: thnx. could u pls confirm tht the one given in my reference $y=x\cos^{-1}a+C$ is incomplete, ie. does not take in to accout all possible cases right ?

Comment: I said that in my first sentence, "The solution is not unique"